# Direction of motion of particle when placed on line of force

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

An electric line of force in the $x-y$ plane is given by equation $x^2+y^2=1$. A particle with unit positive charge, initially at rest at the point **x=1,y=0** will move along the circular line of force.
**True/False**

My attempt:

True because the lines of force give the direction of Electric field and hence the force.
But the answer given is False. :/
Where am I wrong?

Also, how can the field line form a closed loop if the field is supposed to be conservative in nature?

Comment: Think about the force which needs to be available to provide the centripetal acceleration.

Comment: but in that case the field lines would have to be radially inwards right?

Comment: So now do you have an answer?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand this. The question says that the field lines are circular and they don't point inwards.

Comment: You have already answered the question in a previous comment......right?

Comment: Can you help me think of this in some other way?

Comment: Why and how will the lines be radially inwards... This is not what the question states

Comment: They are not and so you can now answer the question.  I am sorry if I confused you.

Comment: So the books answer is incorrect

Comment: The books answer of "False" is correct.

Comment: Ok now I am really confused and even after having thought about it I can't seem to get it. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

electric field vector just as described is very much possible when magnetic field changes {topic for another time, curl of electric field isn't zero always} to answer your question, EF and force point in same direction, in circular motion, it is a necessity that there is a force pointing towards the centre of circle ,here, it is in no way possible. only tangential force will initially move it in the direction you think but quickly diverge away from that path

Answer (score 0):

Karan Singh, both the statements in the question are false. Including x2+y2=1 .That is why the answer is false.
Field lines are radial, not curved for electric charge.

Answer (score 0):

The direction of the force is given by the tangent to the line of force (ie electric field vector) at the point where the particle is currently situated.

If the particle were already moving and this force were directed **radially** towards the origin, then it could continue moving in a circle at constant speed. However, in this case the force is not radially inward, it is directed **tangentially**. There is no centripetal force, so it cannot move in a circle.

As soon as the particle begins to move in response to the electric force, it will no longer be on the same line of force. Its inertia will carry it slightly further outwards at each step, as well as moving round the circle. The particle will not move in a circle; it will spiral outwards.

According to the [Maxwell-Faraday equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction#Maxwell.E2.80.93Faraday_equation) an electric field line can be closed if it is generated by a changing magnetic field. In this case the electric field is **not conservative**.